# Foundry Workshop or Quiver - Aggregation editable by user in view mode, is it possible?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is it possible in Workshop or Quiver to expose an aggregated bar chart where **aggregation property is changeable** by user (in reading mode). For instance by offering to user a dropdown that lists properties to aggregate on.

I guess the function presented [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325853/how-to-have-flexible-grouping-column-in-foundry-functions) can do the job. And then it should be a story to create dropdown widget and chart plugged on the function result. But I miss experience in Workshop or Quiver. Can some one help me with more detail ? Thank you by advance.

> I want to move from Slate to Workshop/Quiver applications without loosing this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a Function-backed chart and the approach you linked to.

Another option is to change your data structure to a "metrics"-style schema like:

`|id|main_object_foreign_key|type|timestamp|value`

And then make a chart based on *filtering* on the metric **type** property with the series *also* set to the **Type** value.

This effectively lets the user control what "metrics" to show on the chart by providing them with a filter element.

There are some downsides with this approach, but adding a representation of your data in this format can bring a lot of flexibility to certain kinds of visualization or workflow building needs.

Comment: I choosed the function backed solution and was able to implement it after some efforts. One side effect if the workshop chart selection can not be used to filter other widget (let's say a table for instance). I Will keep in mind you 2nd solution also.